# Best firewall to block Tor Browser: FortiGate or Sophos XG?

Tags: firewall

Users who use wifi of the netrwork shouldn't be able to connect to the internet via Tor Onion Browser, for that reason I am looking for a hardware based firewall (entry-level).
So far I found the FortiGate series of FortiNet and the Sophos XG line. Can someone recommend one of these or are there others?